# Swift 4 Get related data from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Guys i want to get **image** from **JSON** for specific **category**. I use Alamofire to get data from JSON. I can get separate all images and all category. What i want to do is: for example if **category** == **Bar**, i want to get **category_image**.

```
case let x where x == "Bar" || x == "Sashimi" || x == "Pizza": imageName = "cafe"
    Alamofire.request("http://95.46.59.150:9095/api/v1/institution/get-all-institutions", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let objJson = response.result.value as! [String: Any]? {
                for (key,value) in objJson {
                    if let result2:[[String:Any]] = value as? [[String:Any]]{
                        for dict in result2 {
                            for (key,value) in dict {
                                if key["category"] == "bar"{
                                }
                                if key == "category_image" {
                                    if let str1: String = value as? String {
                                        Allimages.append(str1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        }
```

**JSON**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "socials": {
            "vk": "https://vk.com/cafe_teplominsk",
            "instagram": "https://www.instagram.com/teplo_cafe/",
            "facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/cafeteplominsk"
        },
        "short_title": "#тепло",
        "title": "Кафе #тепло",
        "latitude": "53.93820000",
        "longitude": "27.58520000",
        "image": "https://static.relax.by/images/common/catalog_round_logos/d3e4a58f89cdf9ebba2b6759a6e1fe08.jpg",
        "site": "http://cafeteplo.by/",
        "description": "Невозможно представить заведение с более теплой и радушной атмосферой.\r\n\r\nПомимо отличного сервиса и качественного обслуживания кафе #Тепло поразит Вас необыкновенным интерьером в стиле Прованс с абажурами и оригинальными декорациями.\r\n\r\nХорошо там, где #тепло!",
        "phone": "+375 29 639 22 22",
        "work_time": "С 09:00 до 23.00",
        "category": "Bar",
        "category_image": "http://95.46.59.150:9095/storage/photos/microphone.png",
        "features": "{\"Wi-Fi\": \"Есть\", \"Залы\": \"Зал (85 мест) для некурящих\", \"Сайт\": \"cafeteplo.by\", \"Кухня\": \"Европейская, Итальянская\", \"Метро\": \"Академия наук\", \"Район\": \"Советский\", \"В меню\": \"Пицца, Обеденное меню, Завтраки, Морепродукты, Стейки, Доставка еды, Десерты, Салаты и холодные закуски\", \"Банкет\": \"До 16 чел.\", \"Музыка\": \"Тихая фоновая\", \"Курение\": \"Запрещено\", \"Описание\": \"на портале relax.by\", \"Парковка\": \"Есть\", \"Для детей\": \"Да\", \"Кинотеатры\": \"Октябрь\", \"Предоплата\": \"в размере 30%\", \"Средний счет\": \"$$\", \"Кондиционеры\": \"Есть\", \"Тип заведения\": \"Кафе\", \"способ оплаты\": \"Наличный расчет, Безналичный расчет, Оплата пластиковой картой\", \"Пицца на вынос\": \"Есть\", \"Разливное пиво\": \"Zlatý Bažant, Heineken, Ирландское, Бельгийское, Белорусское\", \"Количество мест\": \"85\", \"Торговые центры\": \"Европа\", \"Большая компания\": \"Да\", \"Дисконтные карты\": \"карта друга со скидкой 10%\", \"Популярные места\": \"парк Дружбы Народов (пл. Бангалор), Логойский тракт\", \"Быстро перекусить\": \"Да\", \"Закрытие заведения\": \"Да\", \"Национальная кухня\": \"Итальянская\", \"Романтический ужин\": \"Да\", \"Предварительный заказ\": \"существует\", \"Условия закрытия залов\": \"50 рублей на человека\", \"Оплата пластиковой картой\": \"Есть\", \"Банкет на открытом воздухе\": \"Нет\", \"Условия закрытия заведения\": \"обсуждается с менеджером\", \"Организационные возможности\": \"Банкетное обслуживание, Вечеринки, Выездное обслуживание, Деловые переговоры, День рождения, Конференция, Корпоративное обслуживание, Организация детских праздников, Презентации, Свадьба, Семинар\", \"Количество залов под мероприятия\": \"1\", \"Что клиент может принести с собой\": \"обсуждается при составлении предзаказа\", \"Владение персоналом иностранными языками\": \"Английский\"}",
        "address": "Минск, ул.Богдановича 138",
        "created_at": "20.07.2017 13:10:42",
        "updated_at": "13.07.2018 13:36:02"
    },
```

Comment: Did you post the wrong `json` in question as in the accepted answer `data` is not an `array` but in the above `json` it is an `array`?

Comment: @Kamran
i change the 2nd line like that... 
guard let json = response.value as? [String : Any] else { return}
guard let data = json["data"] as? [[Sring : Any]] else { return }

Comment: It means `data["category"] as? String` is also wrong?

Comment: @Kamran i can post you my code if you want

Comment: @Kamran
switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let json = response.value as? [String : Any]
                let data = json!["data"] as? [[String: Any]]
                for obj in data!{
                    if obj["category"] as? String == condition{
                        imageView.downloadedFrom(link: "\(obj["category_image"])")
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

Comment: i will add it to my post... wait a sec

Comment: No, i just wanted to confirm that the code in the accepted answer is not 100% correct. It gives a pointer but it will not work as it is according to the json structure you have.

Comment: Its like 90% correct.. just put closures and get category in FOR  for obj in data!

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to iterate over response dictionary. Cast `response.value` to dictionary, extract `data` object from it, cast `data` to dictionary and check for whatever you need

```
guard let json = response.value as? [String : Any] else { return}
guard let data = json["data"] as? [Sring : Any] else { return }
guard let category = data["category"] as? String else { return }
if (category == "bar") {
{
    let imageUrl = data["category_image"]
}
```